# i3 3210 do all 4 threads run at once

Tags: windows-7, threads, intel-core-i3

windows 7, task manager show%s thread 1,2,3 all running around 40% thread 4 is at 2%. Is this normal? i3 3210 windows 7 8GB DRAM cpu running at 35% per task manager

Comment: It depends entirely on what programs are running. Maybe, maybe not normal.

Answer (score 0):

When not under full load, this is pretty much normal operation. If under full load, the cores have a massive difference between them i.e. not all of the cores/threads are running at 100%, then that would be a problem.